# cassandra 4.0 -native-transport-requests

Tags: cassandra

Application jobs are running longer in cassandra 4.0.6 when compared with cassandra 3.11.3

Cassandra 4.0.6 and cassandra 3.11.3 are tested with same Application code.

Cassandra 4.0.6 and cassandra 3.11.3 are running on servers which have identical ram, cpu's and disks.
Cluster consists of 5 nodes, all nodes are in same data center.

From the below chart, No of completed requests for pools - "MutationStage, RequestResponseStage,Native-Transport_Requests" are far less in cassandra 4.0.6 when compared with Cassandra 3.11.3.

Can you please provide me some insights what settings I need to tweak in order to increase the completed requests for pools - MutationStage, RequestResponseStage,Native-Transport_Requests

[image]

Our upgrade testing is on hold due to above issues.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Your question is missing a few details. The general guidance is that you (a) provide a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace; (b) describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and (c) steps to replicate the problem. Cheers!